# Selenium - How to import all settings from an existing Firefox profile

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox

**Why am I doing this:**

I need to automate a website that requires client-side SSL certificates. I understand this to be an option which cannot be specified using fp.set_preference(). I am not in control of the server I am connecting to thus I cannot change the security setup.

**What have I tried**

I have created a separate Firefox profile which has the required 'client-side password protected SSL certificates' set up, select one certificate automaticaly and some manual proxy settings (SOCKS 5). After much googling I have set my code as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://www.paininneck.co.uk'
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r"""C:\Users\
<user>\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<Firefox>""")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.get(url)
```

**The Problem:**

The browser does open, however, it is still using the default profile. None of the settings I have changed in the other profile has copied across. The profile specified in my code is still working with selecting it through the Firefox UI.

I am hoping I missed something simple and all this time googling has not been in vain! I am reluctant to change to default settings, however after tweaking the default profile to see if the settings would copy over it is apparent that they don't and Selenium is making a clean copy each time.

Kind regards

Rich

**Versions:**

```
Python==3.6.1,
Selenium==3.4.3,
Firefox==53
gecko driver==v0.16.1
OS==Windows(Its for work dont judge me!)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Selenium 3.4.x, Python 3.6.1 along with geckodriver v0.16.1 & Mozilla Firefox 53.0, you can use the existing Firefox profile through the following steps:

1. Locate the Firefox Profile directory on your windows box. For e.g. my Firefox Profile `"debanjan"` was located at `C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles` by the name `w8iy627a.debanjan`.
2. Next, you have to specify the absolute path of the Firefox Profile directory when you initiate the `webdriver`.
3. Here is the working code which opens an existing Firefox Profile `'debanjan'` on my Windows machine:

   > It is to be noted that the current Selenium-Python binding is unstable with geckodriver and looks to be Architecture specific. You can find the github [discussion](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884) and [merge](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/pull/685) here. So you may additionally need to pass the absolute path of the firefox binary while initializing the **webdriver**

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

   profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\w8iy627a.debanjan')
   binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')

   driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
   url = 'https://www.paininneck.co.uk'
   driver.get(url)
   ```

Comment: I changed the directory of the profile to point to the version in Roaming, I had previously used the version in Local. I don't know what the difference between the two is but it has fixed the problem. Thank you for your help.